# Golang html templates - How to remove the stale cache?

Tags: go, templates, browser-cache

I'm working on a web application built on Golang stdlib templates. My biggest problem is the browser doesn't change the previous content even though a new / updated change in html is developed and compiled.

How will I completely remove the cache generated by the template every time I update the template html? This will improve my workflow.

While developing SPA, I keep changing a hidden value in the page rendered so that a new view is made available (removing the cache effectively). What could be done to in a server rendered webpage that shows only cached content. I keep commenting and uncommenting {{.}} in the template, but that too doesn't work all the time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: But I'm surprised that Chrome keeps showing the same data even after all the browsing data is removed. 
How to work around this situation as my changes in the Golang templates are not reflecting.